# How to fetch Laravel Query Builder return Non associative Result

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, query-builder

I'm new to laravel my previous project i used [Datatable Jquery](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html)
Server side processing.

My table was

```
Id    Name   Age    Status
1     Aaa    18      1
2     Abb    18      1
3     Acc    18      2
```

If am fetching result from database it in Laravel it retrieves  following

```
array(
0=>object(stdClass){
 ["id"]=> 1,
 ["Name"]=>  "Aaa",
 ["Age"]=> 18,
 ["Status"]=>1 
 },
 1=>object(stdClass){
 ["id"]=> 1,
 ["Name"]=>  "Abb",
 ["Age"]=> 18,
 ["Status"]=>1 
 } ,
 2=>object(stdClass){
 ["id"]=> 3,
 ["Name"]=>  "Acc",
 ["Age"]=> 18,
 ["Status"]=>1 
 } )
```

etc..,

But I need

```
array(
  0=>{  
     1,
     Aaa,
     18,
     1},
  1=>{  
     2,
     Abb,
     18,
     1},
,
  2=>{  
     3,
     Acc,
     18,
     1});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of a query will be a collection. So, you can use the [`map()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-map) collection method with `array_values()`:

```
$collection->map(function($i) {
    return array_values($i->toArray());
})->toArray();
```

And if it's an array for some reason, use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
array_map(function($i) {
    return array_values((array)$i);
}, $array);
```